# Save file name and extension based on another file with .to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input file name `file_a.xml`

I already created a function to parse out the xml and save it as a df. Then I used `df.to_csv`
to save the output file name `file_a.csv`

Is there a way to do this automatically with default filename and extension?
I need to iterate over a folder with lots of .xml files, so I like to the output filename & extension it based on the input xml file.

```
xml_file = open ('file/path/dir/file_a.xml','r').read()

def XML_to_CSV(xml_file):
    ...code to parse out xml...
    return df 

csv_data = df.to_csv('file/path/dir/file_a.csv',index = False)
```

Comment: Look at https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/ or a similar `pathlib` tutorial.

Comment: @PM77-1 - thanks! I was able to use `pathlib` to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

for file in os.listdir("your dir"):
    if file.endswith(".xml"):
        ...make the xml turn df.
        df.to_csv(Path(file).stem + '.csv', index=False)
```